# Chrome Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf

I am unable to download the pdf. I am converting base64 string to blob and tries to download the pdf. Chrome throws an error saying "Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL" if I use the below code. But it works in all other browsers.

```
const link = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.setAttribute('href', blob);
link.setAttribute('download', pdfName);
```

If I change the above code as below it works. I am unable to find the root cause of it. Can anyone tell me what caused this issue?

```
const link = document.createElement('a');
// document.body.appendChild(link);
link.href = blob;
link.download = pdfName;
```